# F5 integration on ansible

Tags: ansible, f5

Until now, I used the core module of Ansible.

Now I would play also with Extra Module. Let's say that I want to use on my playbook: bigip_partition. 
I've seen that it is in https://github.com/F5Networks/f5-ansible/tree/master/library

Could someone tell me how to install them?
I'm on Ubuntu 14LTS, Ansible 2.2

At the moment:

```
> sudo pip install bigsuds --upgrade pip 
> sudo pip install f5-sdk 
> sudo pip install git+https://github.com/F5Networks/f5-ansible.git -vvv
Collecting git+https://github.com/F5Networks/f5-ansible.git
  Cloning https://github.com/F5Networks/f5-ansible.git to /tmp/pip-NjrWJw-build
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/F5Networks/f5-ansible.git /tmp/pip-NjrWJw-build
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-NjrWJw-build/setup.py) egg_info for package from git+https://github.com/F5Networks/f5-ansible.git
    Running command python setup.py egg_info
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-NjrWJw-build/setup.py'
Cleaning up...
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-NjrWJw-build/
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 634, in _prepare_file
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 129, in prep_for_dist
    self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 439, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 707, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-NjrWJw-build/
```

Thanks,
Riccardo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`https://github.com/F5Networks/f5-ansible` is not a python package, don't try to install it with pip.
To use those modules you just need to put py-files from `library` to your `playbook-path/library`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have a much better experience if you install the 'App Services 3.0' (AS3) declarative interface on you BIG-IP:
https://clouddocs.f5.com/products/extensions/f5-appsvcs-extension/3/

Then you just send 'declarations' of your desired state, instead of working with MANY imperative interfaces...

Here are some example declarations (which are easy to generate/manipulate in Ansible using Jinja2 templates):
https://clouddocs.f5.com/products/extensions/f5-appsvcs-extension/3/userguide/examples.html